# log not generated in Superset 0.24

Tags: apache-superset

I have done following log configuration in superset_config.py file -

```
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s'
LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
ENABLE_TIME_ROTATE = False
TIME_ROTATE_LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
FILENAME = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'log', 'superset.log')
ROLLOVER = 'midnight'
INTERVAL = 1
BACKUP_COUNT = 30
```

But logs are not generated in my DATA_DIR/log/superset.log file, is there any configuration missing?

Answer (score 2):

Change **ENABLE_TIME_ROTATE = False** to **ENABLE_TIME_ROTATE = True**